# Does Destiny require a license transfer if your are transferring data to a new HDD?

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I have an Xbox 360 and I need to data transfer all of my data to a larger hard drive before the third DLC comes out for Destiny. As I have learned whilst researching when you data transfer you may also need to license transfer as well before playing some games.

I have Destiny downloaded from the marketplace onto my hard drive and destiny is only allowed to be downloaded onto a hard drive. However, someone already did a license transfer without my knowledge on my account, thus I will have to wait for my next license transfer (which will be months away).

So my question is: Does Destiny require a license transfer if your are transferring data?

I ask this because I will not be able to play the third DLC upon arrival unless I transfer it, and unless I can avoid doing a license transfer somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what a "License Transfer" is referring to is the rights to that content that exist on your *current* Xbox. This means that whenever you're offline, you can still access any downloaded content (provided you have the profile with that linked (System) license currently logged in).

From the [Xbox Support Q&A](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/downloadable-content/download-content)

> You receive a license to use content when you purchase that content. The license has two parts:
>
> - The system license. This license applies to the gamertag that purchases the content.
> - The local license. This license applies to the console to which you first downloaded the content.

To explain; the **System License** is the license that is attached to your profile, making that profile the "owner" of the content.

The **Local License** on the other hand, sits on the Xbox, and determines whether or not this content can be accessed offline. If the current Xbox does *not* have this license, the content *cannot* be accessed without an active internet connection.

So to answer your question: It purely depends on whether or not you intend to play this game offline or not.

- If you do wish to play offline: Yes; you will need to transfer the Local License
- If you *don't* wish to play offline: No; you shouldn't need to bother. That being said, it won't hurt either way.

Comment: @jakey2525 if this answers your question, please remember to accept the answer by clicking on the "tick" on the left hand side of the answer. This will indicate to future users that the answer helped solve this issue.

Comment: Last time I played, Destiny had nothing even resembling "playing online".

Comment: @Amadeus9 I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to, or what your point is... primarily this game *is* an online, free roam FPS/Action-RPG. It's been quite a while since I've played, but I don't actually believe you can even play this game off-line at all. That aside, this question isn't even about the game - it's asking about the licenses required to play games in general on or off-line.